# changes required in junit test cases on using preAuthorize annotation to api generated through Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security, jhipster

I created a jhipster project and added an entity(entity name **Pressure**). All the codes of rest controller, service, repository and junit test cases are auto generated through jhipster.

I protected the create, update and delete api of the entity by adding annotation

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

The default junit test cases fails for these protected api when i run

```
./mvnw verify
```

The error is in the format

```
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   PressureResourceIT.createPressure:210 Status expected:<201> but was:<403>
[ERROR]   PressureResourceIT.createPressureWithExistingId:251 Status expected:<400> but was:<403>
[ERROR]   PressureResourceIT.deletePressure:2629 Status expected:<204> but was:<403>
[ERROR]   PressureResourceIT.updateNonExistingPressure:2611 Status expected:<400> but was:<403>
[ERROR]   PressureResourceIT.updatePressure:2573 Status expected:<200> but was:<403>
```

I understand that auto generated test codes are not able to handle api that are later protected using preAuthorize annotation, that's why the status code 403 (forbiden).

I need help, to know what modifications are required to the junit test case code. Say for example, what changes will be required to below test case?

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createPressureWithExistingId() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = pressureRepository.findAll().size();

        // Create the Pressure with an existing ID
        pressure.setId(1L);

        // An entity with an existing ID cannot be created, so this API call must fail
        restPressureMockMvc.perform(post("/api/pressures").with(csrf())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(pressure)))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

        // Validate the Pressure in the database
        List<Pressure> pressureList = pressureRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(pressureList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing specific to JHipster here, Spring security has all you need, in particular you could annotate your test with `@WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN")`

See official docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#running-as-a-user-in-spring-mvc-test-with-annotations

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get are actually very good, and exactly the point of using these tests.

You are getting back a 403 response which means: Unauthorized. The reason for this is that when you are not logged in as an Admin, you are not allowed to access those endpoints.

You should adapt your failing testcase to the new situation, where you need an admin to be logged in for those endpoints

add: `@WithMockUser(roles="ADMIN")` to your testcase to mock the user being logged in as an admin

And also, you could add testcases that succeed when you are **not** logged in as an admin, but you still try to access these endpoints (the state your testcases are in now). These combinations should result in a 403 response. Add the assertion:

```
.andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
```